# Pass string variable to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I'm trying to pass a string value to button onclick event 
but javascript function not reading anything from variable x

```
<button class="btn btn-buy" onclick="myFunction(@item.ProductId.ToString())" style="@btnstyle"><h4>Add to Basket</h4></button>
```

How do I pass variable values to Java script parameter ?

```
   <script>
            function myFunction(x) {
                 alertify.prompt('Prompt Title', x, '1'
                    , function (evt, value)
                    {

                    }
                    , function () { 
                    alertify.error('Cancel') });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `myFunction('@item.ProductId.ToString()')`, I mean value of `@item.ProductId.ToString()` should be quoted?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you just need to put the value in quotes, razor will put the value of `@item.ProductId.ToString()` directly into the html, but it won't be in quotes, so when the browser interprets it as javascript it will be rather confused.

It's helpful to remember when you're working with razor that it's a templating system which outputs a document which will then be interpreted by the browser. `@item.ProductId.ToString()` just puts some text into that template. Javascript has no access to that variable, except as it is made available through the template. For this reason, it needs to be surrounded by something to make javascript treat it as a string. Practically this means surrounding it with quotes, as in `"@item.ProductId.ToString()"`

As an example:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  console.log(x)
  alertify.prompt('Prompt Title', x, '1', function(evt, value) {

  }, function() {
    alertify.error('Cancel')
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alertify.js/0.5.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-buy" onclick="myFunction('test')" style="@btnstyle"><h4>Add to Basket</h4></button>
```

In that example if `'test'` were not surrounded by quotes, it'd be undefined, as it's looking for a variable named test:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  console.log(x)
  alertify.prompt('Prompt Title', x, '1', function(evt, value) {

  }, function() {
    alertify.error('Cancel')
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/alertify.js/0.5.0/alertify.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-buy" onclick="myFunction(test)" style="@btnstyle"><h4>Add to Basket</h4></button>
```

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined",

Comment: @sansalk sorry if I haven't been clear. My point was that, if `test` isn't a string, it will throw the error. In the first example, you'll notice that it _is_ a string, so doesn't throw. In your code, razor will put text in the place of `@item.ProductId.ToString()`, but because it will not have quotes, javascript will attempt to interpret it as a variable, which will almost certainly be undefined

Comment: Thanks, Oliver can you show a working example for variable passing then

Answer (score -2):

assuming `@item.ProductId.ToString()` you're trying to call JS's toString() method, then you need to call `.toString` with a lowerCase t, and not a capital `T`.

Comment: OP is using `C#`'s `ToString()` method. I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: aha, i shouldn't have assumed. :D